# Gnuplot: how to use eval with for loop

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script to plot 100 data files of `(x,y)` format. Now I would like to do a linear `y=m*x + b` fit of each set of data and get the corresponding `m,b` values for each set of data. The script crashes when it gets to the **eval** command. Since the **do for** syntax is not supported in gnuplot 4.4 (which I am using), can anyone tell me how to use **eval** correctly in the **for loop**? My script is as follows:

```
# template.gnuplot
set terminal postscript enh color 24
plotfile = "graph.eps"
set output plotfile
filename(n) = sprintf("%d_mod.int", n)
plot for [i = 1:100] filename(i) u 1:2 title sprintf("%d", i) w lp
fstr(n) = sprintf('f%d(x) = m%d*x + b%d', n)
fitstr(n) = sprintf('fit ''%d_mod.int'' f%d(x) via m%d,b%d', n)
eval fstr(i) for [i = 1:100]
eval fitstr(i) for [i = 1:100]
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not upgrading ? That would be the easiest.

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.6 but the **do for** command is only carried out once (instead of 100 times). What is the syntax for doing a line fit within the loop structure?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking then this question is the same as [gnuplot linear fit within for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24367146/2604213) for which you got an answer, correct? If yes, could you please delete this question?